# Include static library in Swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linker, frameworks

I'm trying to write a Swift wrapper around a static library in C/C++.

The entire library consists of multiple static libraries (*.a) and header files.

My file structure looks like this:

```
Info.plist
module.modulemap
MyFrameworkProject.h
Wrapper/
    WrapperClass.swift
Dependencies/
    third_party_lib_1/
        include/
            main_1.h
            subh1.h
            subh2.h
        lib/
            libtp_1.a
    third_party_lib_2/
        include/
            main_2.h
            subh1.h
            subh2.h
        lib/
            libtp_2.a
    third_party_lib_3/
        include/
            main_3.h
            subh1.h
            subh2.h
        lib/
            libtp_3.a
```

With the following content of `module.modulemap`:

```
module MyFrameworkInternalUtils {
    header "Dependencies/third_party_lib/include/main_1.h"
    export *
}
```

Where `main_1.h` contains all declarations I want to use in my Swift wrapper.

I've added `Dependencies/third_party_lib/include` to the project's `Header Search Paths` and I've added the libraries to the "Link Binary with Static Libraries" Build Phase.

However, when building the project, I'm getting error messages complaining "assert" and "jmp_buf" are not declared. These are declared in files like `third_party_lib_3/sub1.h` and "third_party_lib_2/sub2.h" though. And `third_party_lib_1/main.h` includes these files recursively (meaning `third_party_lib_1/main.h` includes `third_party_lib_2/main.h` and `third_party_lib_2/main.h` includes `third_party_lib_2/sub2.h`).

I'm guessing this has to do with the Header Search Path/Include path but I can't figure out what exactly.

What am I missing? It's already taken me some time to get used to LLVM's modulemap file format.

Comment: Add all headers that are required, into the module map.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk What would I do if that's more than 100 headers? Afaik the order of inclusion matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `umbrella header` in modulemap instead of `header`.

1. Create `MyFrameworkInternalUtils.h` in which you include all umbrella headers from all static libs (i.e. `#include <third_party_lib_1/main_1.h>`).
2. Define this `MyFrameworkInternalUtils.h` as an umbrella header of the module,

like this:

```
module MyFrameworkInternalUtils {
    umbrella header "MyFrameworkInternalUtils.h"
    export *
}
```

For more information, check what the module map language has to offer, [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-map-language).

Comment: Now it's complaining "`third_party_lib_3/include/subdir/subsub2.h`
 file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead".

Comment: Is the preprocessor complaining in the `MyFrameworkInternalUtils.h` header, or is the complaint coming from the module map?

Comment: It's complaining within the header files. Do I need to add each of them to the "Header Search Path"?

Comment: So, the path in angled brackets should be relative to the folder that you specify in "Header Search Paths". If you specify the "/Path/To/Dependencies/" there, then the relative path in angled brackets has to start with `<third_party_lib_1/path/to/main1.h>`. Also, each third party lib relies on certain  folder starting from which it is including its own headers, thus, you might also need to define path to each `include` folder of each third party lib in search paths. It's hard to say something more defenitive without actually knowing the folder structure and seeing headers in libs.

Comment: `you might also need to define path to each include folder of each third party lib in search paths` I did that. And got it building successfully. However, when using the framework in an app, it comes up with the same message about angled brackets (I'm guessing it's not aware of the base path).

Comment: Using framework is another story - you should copy all headers that are directly or indirectly exported by modulemap, into framework’s `Headers` folder preserving the headers folder structure, before you can actually use the framework. So you’d better have a consistent folder structure between the umbrella headers.

Comment: You can check how OpenCV iOS framework headers are shipped by cocoapods.

Comment: Do I have to copy all of them even if I don’t won’t them to be publicly exposed but just use them within the framework to build a swift wrapper around them?

Comment: You need to copy all headers that are included in other public headers

Comment: Hm, I don't intend to expose any of the headers to the user of the framework though -- all of them should be used internally by the framework by the Swift wrapper only. The user will only see the Swift wrapper.